# PowerPoint slideShow: Hidden slides become visible after visiting them

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have this presentation in which there's a "menu" to go to 3 different slides which are hidden, the purpose is to access this slides only through the menu. The thing is that if I go to one of this slides through the menu, and I press enter/left or right keys/pg up pg down, i can go to the other hidden slides, is like once they're visited they are not hidden anymore. Any ideas?

I've already tried this:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/after-hyperlinking-to-a-hidden-slide-all-hidden/b5521279-e2a4-482a-a58c-85c47b67e251

But the thing is that if I'm in a hidden slide and press Enter or a key I go to the begining of the main presentation, not the following slide (and skipping the hidden ones)

I'm attaching an example (please try downloading the file as online powerpoint doesn't work exactly as desktop version: https://azist-my.sharepoint.com/:p:/g/personal/tomas_azist_onmicrosoft_com/EQEc3tX-TyNEvnbabj5VRNYBmnPFVCzReb9dMlkl_wk_rw?e=lAVjKI

Edit: I'm using Windows 10, Office 365, I'll post exact versions later.

Thanks!

Comment: Please mention the *exact* version of Office and of Windows/MacOS, and if Windows, the "bitness" of both Windows and Office.

Comment: One approach would be to set the presentation to play in Kiosk mode (Slide Show tab, Set Up Slide show button). This disables the usual spacebar/arrow-key/etc keystrokes from navigating the show. You'd have to provide some kind of navigation buttons on the slides where you want the user to be able to advance normally, but (just tested with your presentation) this will prevent the user from moving from one hidden slide to the next.